# ECOS solver stops working in CVXPY 1.0 version

Tags: python, lasso-regression, cvxpy

I was working with cvxpy 0.4 version, and in this version I had programmed the group lasso penalized linear model as follows:

```
from cvxpy import *
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np
boston = load_boston()
x = boston.data
y = boston.target
index = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5])
lambda_val = 1
```

#### 0.4 version

```
n = x.shape[0]
lambda_param = Parameter(sign="positive")
index = np.append(0, index)
x = np.c_[np.ones(n), x]
group_sizes = []
beta_var = []
unique_index = np.unique(index)
for idx in unique_index:
    group_sizes.append(len(np.where(index == idx)[0]))
    beta_var.append(Variable(len(np.where(index == idx)[0])))
num_groups = len(group_sizes)
group_lasso_penalization = 0
model_prediction = x[:, np.where(index == unique_index[0])[0]] * beta_var[0]
for i in range(1, num_groups):
    model_prediction += x[:, np.where(index == unique_index[i])[0]] * beta_var[i]
    group_lasso_penalization += sqrt(group_sizes[i]) * norm(beta_var[i], 2)
lm_penalization = (1.0 / n) * sum_squares(y - model_prediction)
objective = Minimize(lm_penalization + (lambda_param * group_lasso_penalization))
problem = Problem(objective)
lambda_param.value = lambda_val
problem.solve(solver=ECOS)
beta_sol = [b.value for b in beta_var]
```

#### 1.0 Version

```
n = x.shape[0]
lambda_param = Parameter(nonneg=True)
index = np.append(0, index)
x = np.c_[np.ones(n), x]
group_sizes = []
beta_var = []
unique_index = np.unique(index)
for idx in unique_index:
    group_sizes.append(len(np.where(index == idx)[0]))
    beta_var.append(Variable(shape=(len(np.where(index == idx)[0]), 1)))
num_groups = len(group_sizes)
model_prediction = 0
group_lasso_penalization = 0
model_prediction = x[:, np.where(index == unique_index[0])[0]] * beta_var[0]
for i in range(1, num_groups):
    model_prediction += x[:, np.where(index == unique_index[i])[0]] * beta_var[i]
    group_lasso_penalization += sqrt(group_sizes[i]) * norm(beta_var[i], 2)
lm_penalization = (1.0 / n) * sum_squares(y.reshape((n, 1)) - model_prediction)
objective = Minimize(lm_penalization + (lambda_param * group_lasso_penalization))
problem = Problem(objective)
lambda_param.value = lambda_val
problem.solve(solver=ECOS)
beta_sol = [b.value for b in beta_var]
```

While using the 1.0 code version, it shows this error message:
[image]

So, I think I have migrated correctly the code from version 0.4 to 1.0 but a problem that in 0.4 version was solved with ECOS solver, in 1.0 version shows an error message. Am I doing something wrong here? Just in case it matters, I am runnig this code in miniconda python 2.7, in a windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your code isn't consistent with respect to the `beta_var`s. In the 0.4 example they are one dimensional, but in 1.0 example they are 2 dimensional. Here's a simple program that shows cvxpy is consistent:

```
import cvxpy
print(cvxpy.__version__)
from cvxpy import *
try:
    x = Variable(shape=(3, 3))
except TypeError:
    x = Variable(3, 3)
obj = Minimize(norm(x, 2))
Problem(obj).solve(solver=ECOS)
```

Output from 0.4:

```
0.4.11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cvxtest.py", line 11, in <module>
    Problem(obj).solve(solver=ECOS)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 209, in solve
    return self._solve(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 321, in _solve
    solver.validate_solver(constraints)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/solvers/solver.py", line 131, in validate_solver
    self._reject_problem("it cannot solve semidefinite problems")
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/solvers/solver.py", line 156, in _reject_problem
    raise SolverError(message)
cvxpy.error.SolverError: The solver ECOS cannot solve the problem because it cannot solve semidefinite problems.
```

Output from 1.0:

```
1.0.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cvxtest.py", line 11, in <module>
    Problem(obj).solve(solver=ECOS)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 247, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 357, in _solve
    raise e
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 355, in _solve
    solver=solver)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/reductions/solvers/solving_chain.py", line 143, in construct_solving_chain
    ", ".join([cone.__name__ for cone in cones])))
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Either candidate conic solvers (['ECOS']) do not support the cones output by the problem (PSD), or there are not enough constraints in the problem.
```

In summary you should fix your 1.0 code to make your `Variable`s one dimensional.